# unable to send traces from opentelemetry to quick wit

Tags: open-telemetry, open-telemetry-collector

i am trying to instrument my application with open telemetry, i am trying to send my traces to quick wit. i have installed quick wit in cluster

```
func InitTracer() (*sdktrace.TracerProvider, error) {
    ctx := context.Background()

    headers := map[string]string{
        "signoz-service-name": "myapp",
    }

    client := otlptracegrpc.NewClient(
        otlptracegrpc.WithEndpoint("quickwit cluster installed url:port"),
        otlptracegrpc.WithHeaders(headers),
        otlptracegrpc.WithInsecure(),
    )

    exporter, err := otlptrace.New(ctx, client)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("failed to initialize exporter: %e", err)
    }

    res, err := resource.New(
        ctx,
        resource.WithAttributes(
            attribute.String("service.name", "myapp"),
            attribute.String("library.language", "go"),
        ),
    )
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("failed to initialize resource: %e", err)
    }

    // Create the trace provider
    tp := sdktrace.NewTracerProvider(
        trace.WithSampler(trace.AlwaysSample()),
        sdktrace.WithBatcher(exporter),
        sdktrace.WithResource(res),
    )

    // Set the global trace provider
    otel.SetTracerProvider(tp)

    // Set the propagator
    propagator := propagation.NewCompositeTextMapPropagator(propagation.TraceContext{}, propagation.Baggage{})
    otel.SetTextMapPropagator(propagator)

    return tp, nil
}
```

after running the server and hitting some end REST API endpoints and its giving the expected data, but when i open the quick wit UI no traces are coming and i m getting the below error

```
[GIN] 2024/01/17 - 10:15:06 | 200 |     236.379µs |             ::1 | GET      "/books"
2024/01/17 10:15:11 traces export: rpc error: code = Unimplemented desc = unexpected HTTP status code received from server: 404 (Not Found); transport: received unexpected content-type "application/json"
```